# how can i launch two for loop witch initialize thread in the same time?

Tags: c++, multithreading

hi i want to launch my two for loops in the same time cause when i launch my program the loops are executing sequentially, the problem is to perform my task all threads must be executing in the same time,the threads communicate with each other.

here is my main:

```
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
  max_jobs =  std::atoi(argv[3]);
 int size = std::atoi(argv[1]);
 int size1 = std::atoi(argv[2]);
 std::vector<std::thread> prods(size);
 std::vector<std::thread> consos(size1);


 for (int i=1;i<=size;i++){
   prods[i] = 
std::thread(producer,max_jobs);}
  for (int j =1 ; j<=size1;j++){
  consos[j] = std::thread(consumer);}

  for (int i=1;i<=size;i++){
   prods[i].join();}
  for (int j =1 ; j<=size1;j++){
  consos[j].join();}



return 0;
 }
```

and here is my producer and consumer functions

```
  void producer(int max){
for (int i = 0; i<= max ; i++){
    std::cout << max;
    std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
    std::cout << "production "<< i << endl;
    produced_nums.push(i);
    notified = true;
    cond_var.notify_one();
}
done = true;
cond_var.notify_one();
 std::cout << "\n nombre de thread dans la 
pile est " << produced_nums.size() << endl;
  }


  void consumer(){
 std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
 while(!done){
     while(!notified){
         cond_var.wait(lock);
     }

 while(!produced_nums.empty()){
     cout << "consuming " << produced_nums.top() << endl;
     produced_nums.pop();
 }
 notified = false;
 }
 std::cout << "\n nombre de thread dans la 
pile est " << produced_nums.size() << endl;
 }
```

Comment: `for (int i=1;i<=size;i++)`. C++ uses 0 indexing.

Comment: You are calling `.join`. So of course your code stalls waiting for each thread to finish. That's what you *asked for* so that's what you got. The threads are started and *run* in parallel, but at the end you block waiting for each of them to *finish* in a specific order.

Comment: And use a single loop for both creating and joining the threads.

Comment: Jesper Juhl thanks , so how should i modify my code please